# Typing Animation as Placeholder

Tags: animation, placeholder, typing

A perfect example of this technique can be seen on the https://www.inwx.de/en site. Here the input field with the titel "Find your desired domain" shows an typing effect as a placeholder, where text is typed and deleted. I wanted to ask where to start to build this effect. I couldn't find something on the internet about this "effect". ;)

Comment: Is the problem solved? If yes, please accept my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this one: [typing.js](https://github.com/lihuii/typing.js)

After download the file and link them in your HTML file, you just need to set `var isPlaceholder = true;` and put the text in `var strings = new Array("www.yourdomain.com")`.

Like this:

```
<input id="words" type="text" name="domain" value="" placeholder="">  
<script>
  var strings = new Array("www.yourdomain.com")
  var typingSpeed = 100;
  var deleteSpeed = 40;
  var isLoop = true;
  var isPlaceholder = true;
</script>
```

If you're using this, let me know!
I'd love to see it.